# PHP not uninstalling

Tags: 16.04, apt, php

When I run `sudo apt purge php` I see

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php7.0' is not installed, so not removed
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 320 not to upgrade.
```

However running `php -v` gives

```
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.12 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

What gives? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I've tried `sudo apt purge php7.0` as well and it's the same output as above.

Comment: `php` is a metapackage that refers to multiple packages.  You will have to remove multiple other packages instead.

Comment: @ThomasWard how do I find out what needs to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Start by doing this:

```
sudo apt purge php7.0-common php-common
```

This will tell the system to attempt to remove the 'common shared files' that all versions of PHP share.  This will in turn work to remove the PHP CLI binaries and other binaries related to PHP, and should generate a large list of things to remove.

Note that if you have any webservers installed because you installed PHP (that is, they were installed as a result of `apt install php`) they will be autoremoved as well.

You may want to clean up after with `sudo apt autoremove` to remove any extra leftovers that are no longer needed by your purge calls above.

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt purge php*` instead to remove all PHP related packages